# call a function in ngFor with results to be used in <td> elements

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a service that basically returns an object:

```
  {'health' : 50, 'status':'1A1', 'owner': 'Parent'}
```

and a few more based on a formula. Those results are displayed in table row. In my component.ts I have:

```
      record_info = {}
     itemStatus(item_id) {
          this.record_info = this.itemInformationService.itemStatus(item_id);
        }
```

then component.html:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items; itemStatus(item.id);">
      <td>{{ record_info['health']</td>
      <td>{{ record_info['status']</td>
      <td>{{ record_info['parent']</td>
      </tr>
```

But it is not working. I am trying to avoid returning each info on each  cell since health determines status and status determines parent that it is easier to do them in one method.

The error I am getting is:

]*ngFor="let item of items; itemStatus(item.id);"

Comment: why dont you simply create a new array with the transformed elements from the original one and iterate it in the template? The `ngForOf` directive wasnt designed to be used in the way that you are trying to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is first apply your `itemStatus` function on each of the entries and then iterate over them in your template.

Here is an example

**component.ts**

This will call the function on each of the entries and put the resulting array on records_info

```
  records_info = this.items.map(item => this.itemStatus(item.id));
```

**component.html**

In the template you iterate over the records_info like any array with a *ngFor

```
      <tr *ngFor="let record_info of records_info">
      <td>{{ record_info.health</td>
      <td>{{ record_info.status</td>
      <td>{{ record_info.parent</td>
      </tr>
```

Hope this solves your issue, otherwise let us know